Uk law on voyeurism and definition of reasonable expectation of privacy
I know laws around this topic are ìn flux with a new sharing offence but the taking offence has stalled in parliament so we still use the old voyeurism offence from the soap 2003 in England and Wales.
But what is the position on the reasonable expectation of privacy at home when it comes to voyeurism?
I understand a bedroom or bathroom is private and covert recordings would evidently be considered voyeurism.
But is it not the case that you cannot have a reasonable expectation of privacy at home if you are for example stood in your front room with the curtains open and the lights on completely naked and easily seen from the public street?
I can't really find anything on this because it seems like conceivably it would be more likely to be indecent exposure by the person in that home than voyeurism by anyone walking past able to see that person or record them.
The only reference I found to anything like this is from the law commission asserting that taking pictures of someone undressed in their home, even if clearly visible from the public street would count as voyeurism, but again I don't think there is a reasonable expectation of privacy to stand naked in a room that's visible from the street.
That effectively is exhibitionism like a red light district shop window.

You seem to have summed up the considerations WRT expectation of privacy quite nicely in your question, so what is the actual confusion?

If the viewer can see you  from a public without taking any unusual action (like walking close to your window and looking in), I don't see how it could be considered voyeurism. You don't have any expectation of privacy if you can be seen by anyone on the street.

If you can see somebody standing naked at their window, you might enjoy their sight without risking a prosecution, but that still doesn't mean you can take out your pro camera and take pictures (or even distribute them).

Sexual Offences Act 2003

68 Voyeurism: interpretation
(1) For the purposes of section 67, a person is doing a private act if the person is in a place which, in the circumstances, would reasonably be expected to provide privacy ...

If the circumstances created by the 'victim' make what would normally be a private place public, there is no voyeurism. However, it is possible that the 'victim' has perpetrated the crime of exposure under s66.

As you see there is already a comment that says you wouldn't break any law by watching them but you wouldn't be entitled to record them. Voyeurism doesn't differentiate between the two acts. My question was more about where is the line drawn on expectation of privacy, as I came across an assertion from the law commission that someone in their home albeit viewable from the street would still have an expectation of privacy. It seemed to be a contradiction.

Can you provide a link or reference to that assertion by the law commission?

@RedGrittyBrick it was in the law commissions consultation document on intimate image abuse. 2021. Under the section examining the law relating to voyeurism and taking intimate images. I found it perplexing that the law commission would remark that it would constitute voyeurism to photograph someone that you could see in underwear through the window as you were walking down the street.
